# How to filter json object with multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, elasticsearch, filter

The following is the record of 10 devices for every few minutes. I need to return unique set of the record for each id and each should be only the latest.

How can I do that with elastic search or any other solution would be good.

```
{
    {id: 1, time: 12345}, 
    {id: 2, time: 12346}, 
    {id: 1, time: 12347}, 
    {id: 2, time: 12348}, 
    {id: 1, time: 12349}, 
    {id: 3, time: 12350}, 
    ... // 10 different ids and 10000 records
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to return a collection of objects, one for each id and it should be the object with the latest time value for its respective id?

Comment: @ken out of 10000 records, I will return only 10 records with unique id and latest/largest time value.

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as I can get. Not sure how you would choose which 10 results to return if you had say over 10 unique id's in your original dataset.

```js
var rawData = [
    {id: 1, time: 12345}, 
    {id: 2, time: 12346}, 
    {id: 1, time: 12347}, 
    {id: 2, time: 12348}, 
    {id: 1, time: 12349}, 
    {id: 3, time: 12350}, 
    {id: 4, time: 12351}, 
    {id: 2, time: 12352}, 
    {id: 7, time: 12353}, 
    {id: 5, time: 12354}, 
    {id: 3, time: 12355}, 
    {id: 6, time: 12356}, 
    {id: 3, time: 12357}, 
    {id: 7, time: 12358}, 
    {id: 6, time: 12359}, 
    {id: 9, time: 12360}
]

var maxSet = {};
// Get all of the max values
rawData.forEach(function (currentValue, index, array) {
  var currentMax = maxSet[currentValue.id] || null;
  if(currentMax) {
    if(currentValue.time > currentMax){
      maxSet[currentValue.id] = currentValue.time;
    }
  } else {
    maxSet[currentValue.id] = currentValue.time;
  }
});
console.log(maxSet);
// Convert back to object if necessary
var keys = Object.keys(maxSet);
var resultObjs = [];
for(var key in keys) {
    resultObjs.push({id: keys[key], time: maxSet[keys[key]]});
}
console.log(resultObjs);
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, but I'm working on to resolve it via elastic search because the actual problem is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think , You are looking for this , It will give max `time` with unique `id` :-

```
{
    "_source":false,
    "aggs": {
        "byId": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "byTime": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "time"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```